# Rubocop error: Required path rails_helper could not be resolved

Tags: rubocop, rubocop-rspec

Rubocop is saying that the line `require 'rails_helper'` cannot resolve the path.

I am using Rubocop via Solargraph called by lsm-mode which is inside a Docker container working on a Ruby on Rails project using Rspec.  The Emacs process is running on the local laptop and activating Solargraph using lsm-docker.

The docker compose has three containers, a db container with Postgres, a web container running Rails, and another container for the Solargraph process.  The Solargraph container and the web container are starting from the same image that I'm building.  The build process includes two steps to populate Solargraph:

```bash
( grep -s solargraph /hatred/Gemfile > /dev/null && /root/bin/solargraph download-core && /root/bin/solargraph bundle )
```

I'm using the solargraph executable that is in Bundler's bin directory.

I'm new to Rubocop, Solargraph, and lsm-mode.

In my spec file that was auto generated using `rails g scaffold ...` I have a `require 'rails_helper'`.  Doing `rspec path/to/spec` works in that it finds `rails_helper` (which is in the `spec` directory.  But `rubocop` isn't finding it.

My `.rubocop.yml` file is pretty simple:

```yaml
require:
  - rubocop-rails
  - rubocop-rspec

AllCops:
  NewCops: enable
  Include:
    - '**/*.rb'
    - '**/*.rake'
```

I added the `Include` as part of my debugging process but it didn't change anything.  I had errors that the Rails and RSpec cops were not enabled so I added the `NewCops: enable` line and that solved the issue which indicates that Rubocop is finding my config file.  `print -l **/rails_helper*` gives `spec/rails_helper.rb`.

`rubocop spec/views/import_files/new.html.erb_spec.rb` does not complain about the required file.  `pwdx 1` from within the Solargraph container says that it's current working directory is the app's directory.

My best guess is this is a Rubocop issue so I put the question here rather than in the emacs stack exchange.

Edit: `require 'spec/rails_helper'` still has the problem but `require '/app/spec/rails_helper'` removes the warning.  It is as if I need to set the `load_path` of whatever process is generating the warning.

Answer (score 5):

I've been experiencing this same issue, and I believe it is originating from Solargraph, not RuboCop, via the [`require_not_found` reporter](https://solargraph.org/guides/configuration#reporters):

> `require_not_found` highlights require calls where Solargraph could not resolve a required path. Note that this error does not necessarily mean that the path is incorrect; only that Solargraph was unable to recognize it.

For me, [running `yard gems`](https://solargraph.org/guides/yard) in the project directory resolved other "Required path * could not be resolved" diagnostics, but not the ones flagging `require "rails_helper"` in the "/spec" directory.

This appears to be a bug in Solargraph that has not yet been fixed. For now, the only way to silence the warning appears to be to create or update your [`.solargraph.yml` config file](https://solargraph.org/guides/configuration#configuration) and remove `require_not_found` (as it is part of the default configuration):

```yaml
reporters:
  - rubocop
  - require_not_found
```